# Remove user from a tweet

Tags: python, regex

I have a python script which removes RT i.r retweet from the tweet, # hash tag.. Now I want to remove username as well i.e, a tweet which has @userxyz: i.e. @ symbol followed by username followed by :(colon).. I just want to remove such users: For example if the tweet is "@bugun: MHP’li Kemallettin Yılmaz Bank Asya'ya yapılan intihardır http://t.co/AKxMgMuuSs @bugun http://t.co/fyJbr098tw}" I want to remove @bugun: and get the result as "MHP’li Kemallettin Yılmaz Bank Asya'ya yapılan intihardır http://t.co/AKxMgMuuSs @bugun http://t.co/fyJbr098tw"

Here is my code for hash and RT removal from the tweet:

```
# coding:utf-8
import sys, re
x = open("test.txt", "r")
for line in x:
    z = lambda line: re.compile('\#').sub('', re.compile('RT @').sub('@', line, count=1).strip())
    print z(line)
    saveFile = open("test_result.txt", "a")
    saveFile.write(z(line))
    saveFile.write("\n")
    saveFile.close()
```

Comment: Don't know tweet part, but if `@` is guaranteed to be a user, a simple regex like `@[^:]+:` is all you need.

Comment: In your example `^@\w+: ` Will catch only the first username

Answer (score 1):

Using the sample you gave:

"@bugun: MHP’li Kemallettin Yılmaz Bank Asya'ya yapılan intihardır http://t.co/AKxMgMuuSs @bugun http://t.co/fyJbr098tw}"

The code (Python 3.4):

```
# coding:utf-8
import sys, re
x = open("test.txt", "r")
for line in x:
    z = lambda line: re.compile('\#').sub('', re.compile('^@\w+: ').sub('', line, count=1).strip())
    print (z(line))
    saveFile = open("test_result.txt", "a")
    saveFile.write(z(line))
    saveFile.write("\n")
    saveFile.close()
```

Will output:

`MHP’li Kemallettin Yılmaz Bank Asya'ya yapılan intihardır http://t.co/AKxMgMuuSs @bugun http://t.co/fyJbr098tw`

Answer (score 0):

All you have is find the right regexpr. By the way, I included a hashtag in your example and slightly changed your code to remove the hashtag too -- not sure is actually what you wanted.
The function below will remove any hashtag, and the username following a "RT @" and followed by ": ". Hope that helps.

```
import sys, re

tweet_text = "RT @bugun: MHP’li Kemallettin Yılmaz #Hello Bank Asya'ya yapılan intihardır http://t.co/AKxMgMuuSs @bugun http://t.co/fyJbr098tw"

def transform_tweet(line):
    return re.compile('#\w+ ').sub('', re.compile('RT @\w+: ').sub('', line, count=1)).strip()
```

Running `transform_tweet(tweet_text)`, I have this:

```
"MHP’li Kemallettin Yılmaz Bank Asya'ya yapılan intihardır http://t.co/AKxMgMuuSs @bugun http://t.co/fyJbr098tw"
```